# TensorFlow.js speed in the browser

Tags: javascript, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've trained a simple bidirectional LSTM network in Keras (20 units) and exported the model via

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, 'myModel')
```

The model is 53kb large. In my JavaScript app, I load the model like this

```
var model;
async function loadModel() {;
    model = await tf.loadModel('https://example.com/myModel.json');
}
```

and afterwards I run my predictions with

```
async function predict(input) {
    var pred = model.predict(input);
    ...
}
```

It takes 5-6 seconds till the model is loaded, this is fine. But what bothers me is that every call of predict() also takes 5-6 seconds. Every time. For my use case, I'd need the prediction to be extremely fast, 1 second or less.

My question is: Is this normal? Or is something wrong with my code?

*Edit: Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XygXRP*

BTW, model.predict is blocking the UI - how can I prevent that?

Comment: It's a Surface Book 2, Intel i7 with 1.90GHz 2.11 GHz, 16GB RAM on Chrome (latest version)

Comment: I just measured it, with model.predict() in python it takes roughly 300 milliseconds

Comment: Could you please make a working snippet on http://codepen.io or share a gist ?

Comment: You could consider creating an issue here https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is being blocked because you have not asked the thread to await the results of the prediction, this means that it is running synchronously instead of asynchronously. You can fix this by using the `await` keyword e.g. `var pred = await model.predict(input)`.

The rest of your code appears to be fine and so it looks like the delay is coming from your actual model as I saw my CPU was barely taxed to run your model.

It is worth reading the tensorflowjs blog [post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/introducing-the-model-optimization-toolkit-for-tensorflow-254aca1ba0a3) as they give you examples of how you can improve the efficiency of models to make faster inferences in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing to do: use the 'webgl' backend to get some better vector/matrix operation performance instead of 'cpu' which I believe is native Javascript and is slow AF.